# Swift's Set complexity of equability test

Tags: swift, set, time-complexity

What is in Big-O notation complexity of `==` operation applied on two `Set<T>` instances?

I can't find any info in Apple documentation. Anyone knows something about this. Any source to prove answer will be handy.

Comment: You could probably figure this out yourself using randomly created sets of increasing size

Comment: [Use The Source Luke](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Set.swift#L429)

Comment: From the source, `a == b` appears to have time complexity `O(a.count)`. For each element of `a`, a constant time look-up is done in `b`.

Comment: @MartinR Do you agree? Unfortunately the source of Swift is to complex for me to get 100% certainty.

Comment: Not MartinR, but line 443: `for member in lhs` sure looks like `O(a.count)` to me.

Comment: It seems to be ok for me. @Alexander if you create an answer I will mark its.